# How to run a kubectl command from one pc to another pc without using ssh?

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

I have a set where i run some program in docker and orchestrated suing kubernetes. Now i want to run kubectl command from one my pc to another pc where this setup is running. Yes logicall we can do ssh the make a bash script and run it there. but in long run it wont help me. SO is there any other way we can run these kubectl command in my pc which can get executed in another pc?

I have did it in my own pc it works when i have everything in my pc but i am not sure how to do if it is different pc

Comment: Kubernetes already has a network API, so you should be able to just run `kubectl` locally targeting the remote API server.  Possibly an ssh port forward could help here.  This isn't really a programming-related question, though, and another Stack Exchange site might be a more appropriate place to ask.

Comment: can you send me a link so to refer it ??